# Java rectangle cannot find symbol

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
public class Rec {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Rectangle r1;
   r1 = new Rectangle(2, 5, 15, 15);
   System.out.println(r1.getHeight);
}
}
```

and i get an error like:

```
System.out.println(r1.getHeight);
                        ^
symbol:   variable getHeight
location: variable r1 of type Rectangle
1 error
```

I don't get what is wrong with this code, I'm new user so it may be simple but I couldn't find the problem :(

Comment: `r1.getHeight()`  it's a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke a Java method (and [Rectangle.getHeight()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#getHeight()) is a method), you need a parentheses, like:

```
System.out.println(r1.getHeight());
```

By the way, for a method that accepts arguments, you would put those arguments in between parentheses:

```
// This is a method declaration. It says it returns an integer
// and it accepts two integers as its arguments.
int addTwoNumbers(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

// Somewhere in the code, you could call this method by passing
// two integers in there:
int number1 = 1;
int number2 = 10;
int result = someobject.addTwoNumbers(a, b);
// result is now 11.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `r1.getHeight()` instead of `r1.getHeight` because `getHeight();`  definded in Rectangle class . use for Gets the bounding Rectangle of this Rectangle. [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#getHeight%28%29)